# Differences between "echo $variable" and actual output of it

Tags: android, bash

I'm trying to fix a bash script. The part of relevance is this one:

```
function do_get_apks {(
mkdir -p apks
cd apks
adb shell pm list packages > installed_packages
adb shell pm list packages -3 > installed_packages_user

while read p; do
    # remove trailing 'package'
    package=$(echo "${p/package:/}" | tr -d '\r\n')
    mkdir "$package"
    echo "$package"
    echo "adb shell pm path $package"
    apkpath=$(adb shell pm path "$package")
    echo "$apkpath"
    apkpath1=$(echo "$apkpath" | grep "package")
    echo "$apkpath1"
    apkpath2=$(echo "$apkpath" | grep "package" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
    echo "$apkpath2"
    apkpath=$(adb shell pm path "$package" | grep package | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
    adb pull ${apkpath/package:/} "$package/"
    adb shell dumpsys package "$package" > "$package"/info
done < installed_packages)}
```

Thing is there are incongruities between the output of the command echo `"adb shell pm path $package"` where package is com.mobeam.barcodeService which returns a list of all the packages, and the actual content of the command `"adb shell pm path com.mobeam.barcodeService"`, which returns just package:/system/app/BeamService/BeamService.apk (which is the desired output)

It looks like the script is returning a list of packages instead of the desired one. You can test this script with adb and any Android Device.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the error I'm getting is the following one:

```
adb: error: SendRequest failed: path too long: 3922
adb: error: failed to stat remote object 

'com.samsung.android.provider.filterproviderpackage:com.monotype.android.font.rosemarypackage:com.sec.android.app.DataCreatepackage:com.gd.mobicore.papackage:com.sec.android.widgetapp.samsungappspackage:com.google.android.youtubepackage:com.samsung.android.app.galaxyfinderpackage:com.sec.android.app.chromecustomizationspackage:com.android.providers.telephonypackage:com.sec.android.app.parserpackage:com.google.android.googlequicksearchboxpackage:com.vlingo.midaspackage:com.android.providers.calendarpackage:com.osp.app.signinpackage:com.sec.android.directsharepackage:com.samsung.clipboardsaveservicepackage:com.sec.automationpackage:com.android.providers.mediapackage:com.google.android.onetimeinitializerpackage:com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclockpackage:com.android.wallpapercropperpackage:com.samsung.android.provider.shootingmodeproviderpackage:com.sec.android.app.wfdbrokerpackage:com.sec.android.app.safetyassurancepackage:com.sec.factory.camerapackage:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.servicepackage:com.sec.usbsettingspackage:com.samsung.android.easysetuppackage:com.android.documentsuipackage:com.android.externalstoragepackage:com.sec.factorypackage:com.android.htmlviewerpackage:com.whatsapppackage:com.android.mms.servicepackage:com.android.providers.downloadspackage:com.qualcomm.qti.auth.sampleauthenticatorservicepackage:com.samsung.ucs.agent.bootpackage:com.sec.android.theme.naturalpackage:com.wsomacppackage:com.sec.android.Kiespackage:com.qapp.secprotectpackage:com.sec.android.app.voicenotepackage:com.sec.android.app.easylauncherpackage:com.samsung.knox.rcp.componentspackage:com.sec.android.widgetapp.easymodecontactswidgetpackage:com.samsung.android.intelligenceservice2package:samsunges.sclubpackage:com.sec.di.SmartSelfShotpackage:com.samsung.android.MtpApplicationpackage:com.sec.android.app.factorykeystringpackage:com.sec.android.app.samsungappspackage:com.sec.android.emergencymode.servicepackage:com.google.android.configupdaterpackage:com.sec.android.app.wlantestpackage:com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidgetpackage:com.sec.android.widgetapp.activeapplicationwidgetpackage:com.sec.android.app.billingpackage:com.sec.android.app.minimode.respackage:com.android.defcontainerpackage:com.sec.android.daemonapppackage:com.sec.enterprise.knox.attestationpackage:com.android.vendingpackage:com.android.pacprocessorpackage:com.dsi.ant.service.socketpackage:com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiverpackage:com.sec.android.AutoPreconfigpackage:com.sec.android.providers.securitypackage:com.sec.android.provider.badgepackage:com.android.certinstallerpackage:com.samsung.android.securitylogagentpackage:com.android.carrierconfigpackage:com.google.android.marvin.talkbackpackage:com.sec.android.app.taskmanagerpackage:com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenupackage:com.samsung.SMTpackage:com.sec.android.ofviewerpackage:com.samsung.everglades.videopackage:androidpackage:com.android.contactspackage:com.samsung.hs20providerpackage:com.samsung.android.sm.devicesecuritypackage:com.sec.android.casual2package:com.samsung.android.smartfacepackage:com.android.mmspackage:com.android.nfcpackage:com.android.stkpackage:com.sec.knox.foldercontainerpackage:com.android.backupconfirmpackage:com.sec.android.cloudagent.dropboxoobedummypackage:com.samsung.klmsagentpackage:com.samsung.android.app.memopackage:flipboard.apppackage:com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizardpackage:com.android.statementservicepackage:com.google.android.gmpackage:com.sec.android.app.hwmoduletestpackage:com.sec.bcservicepackage:com.android.calendarpackage:com.sec.modem.settingspackage:com.android.phasebeampackage:com.monotype.android.font.samsungsanspackage:com.sec.android.app.sysscopepackage:com.google.android.instantapps.supervisorpackage:com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooserpackage:com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapppackage:com.sec.android.preloadinstallerpackage:com.sec.android.widgpackage:/system/app/BeamService/BeamService.apk': File name too long
```

Comment: Can you show us the outputs of  `echo "$package"` and `echo "$p"` ( note the double-quotes)

Comment: Echo of package: "com.mobeam.barcodeService"
Echo of p: "package:com.mobeam.barcodeService"

Comment: Well, if the variable is enclosed in double quotes then there is no difference between the value of the variable and the output of the echo. So that makes this a debugging question. SO tries not to be a debugging service. Try running your script with `bash -x` to get detailed line-by-line debug info.